# Can AWS Glue connect to Elasticsearch using IAM authentication?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-elasticsearch

Followed this tutorial: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/ug/tutorial-elastisearch-connector.html

I know using this connector can connect to Aws Elasticsearch, but this still needs AWS Secrets Manager to store the username and password.

Is it possible to use IAM authentication to connect to Elasticsearch, rather than username & password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible to use IAM authentication

No, unfortunately.

The [Elasticsearch Connector for AWS Glue](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/prodview-v5ygernwn2gb6) does not currently support IAM authentication & only supports username and password as an authentication mechanism.

[image]